# Salesforce SOQL Get Several Fields info from Contact object with Multiple Junction Objects

Tags: salesforce, soql

To all salesforce experts I need some help.

I have a main object called Contact (contact__c), a junction object called Contact Event objec (Contact_Event__c) with Contact object, another junction object called Company Affiliation (Company_Affiliation__c) with Contact object as well.

In my c# code, **I need to pass an event Id, to retrieve whoever registered for this event, so multiple contacts info back** (the info can be found via contact_event__c by passing event id), the 4 return fields are required:

contact's name, contact's type, contact's company and event name.

To get contact's name and type it's from the main contact object, event name can be from contact event object. The challenge is to get contact's company info which is from company affiliation custom object.

I'm able to use 2 steps to get above info back, but some events have 1000+ contact registered so the performance is bad.

Is there any way to use a single soql to achieve it? like:

SELECT Account_Name__c, Record_Type_Name__c, Is_Primary__c, contact__r.Name__c, Contact__r.Record_Type_Name__c, From Company_Affiliation__c
where Record_Type_Name__c='Business' and Is_Primary__c = true
and Contact__r.Guid__c in (Select Guid from Contact where ...)

or

SELECT  Event_Name__c, Contact__r.Guid__c,Contact__r.Name__c,Contact__r.Record_Type_Name__c,(Select Account_Name__c from Company_Affiliation__c Where...)
FROM Contact_Event__c WHERE Event__r.CVent_ID__C = '83B88111-15D4-4125-B9A0-F66FE46E26D8'...

Below query works (Thanks so much @eyescream) but **I have to use Event as my main object to pass the event's guid, not Contact as the main object**.

SELECT Id, Guid__c, name,
(SELECT Id, Guid__c, AccountName__c
FROM Company_Affiliations__r where Record_Type_Name__c='Business' and Is_Primary__c = true),
(SELECT Id, Guid__c,Name, Event_Name__c
FROM Contact_Events__r
WHERE Event_External_ID__c = 'E2469609-12E1-48C4-ABFF-D617C87D5EC7')
FROM Contact
WHERE Guid__c = '30303334-4d30-3030-3032-466d4a6c6f00'

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the relations exactly? Contact + 2 related lists (`contact__c -> Contact_Event__c, contact__c -> Company_Affiliation__c`)? Or top-down (`contact__c -> Contact_Event__c -> Company_Affiliation__c`)

Assuming it's 1st, you should be able to get it in one go

```soql
SELECT Id, Name, Name__c, Record_Type_Name__c, Guid__c, 
    (SELECT Id, Name, Event_Name__c
    FROM Contact_Events__r
    WHERE Event_ID__c = '83B88111-15D4-4125-B9A0-F66FE46E26D8'),
    (SELECT Id, Name, Account_Name__c, Record_Type_Name__c, Is_Primary__c
    FROM Company_Affiliations__r
    WHERE Record_Type_Name__c='Business' and Is_Primary__c = true)
FROM Contact__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Contact_Event__c WHERE Event_ID__c = '83B88111-15D4-4125-B9A0-F66FE46E26D8')
```

You'll need to check your relationship names (related list names) in Setup or using "describe" calls but this should be close to what you need.

If the performance is bad - is the `Event_ID__c` marked as external id, unique?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @eyescream Yes, it's the 1st case, by using my query and yours I got the same error: 

    FROM Contact_Event__r
         ^
ERROR at Row:3:Column:10
Didn't understand relationship 'Contact_Event__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Just let u know if I remove the contact_Events__r parentheses section, only keeping Company_Affiliation__r parentheses section, the error message will be: didn't understand 
relationship 'Company_Affiliation__c' in FROM part of query call...
In a short, using parallel select query way doesn't work for me.

Comment: You'll have to work with your Salesforce admin to learn [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm]("relationship names"). I'm saying that structure similar to this should be perfectly fine, but you have some gaps to fill. This query with similar structure works in any SF org in the world: `SELECT Id, Name,
(SELECT LastName, Email FROM Contacts WHERE Email != null),
(SELECT Name, CloseDate FROM Opportunities)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email != null)`

Comment: If you don't have admin handy you can try yourself. Go to SF setup -> object manager -> contact event -> fields. Find the lookup (probably contact__c), write the "child relationship name" down and mentally add `__r` at the end. If it's `abc` - check if `select id, name, (select id, name from abc__r) from contact__c limit 5` is a valid query. Do same with company affiliations and slowly build your way towards my "template"

Comment: your query works eyescream, after I fixed a small typo on my side, but the challenge is: UI will pass me the event guid, not contact guid, and event object doesn't have the direct relationship with company affiliation, only contact does...so I feel it's still hard to use this query structure to get company info back (from company affiliaiton) by passing event guid (using event as the main object)...thanks again!!

Comment: The query goes "up" from event to contact (that's the last WHERE) and then "down", pulls contact with 2 child records, right? If Account_Name__c of primary affiliation is not enough - you can go "up" from company affiliation too, with "dots". Zigzag but it'll work fine. What's the lookup field on affiliation? "Account__c"? "Company__c"? Put ", Account__r.Name, Account__r.BillingCity, Account__r.Owner.Name FROM Company_Affiliations__r" and watch what comes back

Comment: How do you experiment with the queries, maybe you missed the Contact__c -> Company_Affiliations__r bit in the result JSON? https://workbench.developerforce.com/ and Utilities -> REST Explorer is pretty easy to use

Comment: Hi eyescream, I was OOO last week and just came back, you are right, I tried your query again and just realize the last where statement with in does the trick (to allow the event guid passing in), it works perfectly fine and performance is decent (600ms to return 700 contacts). 
Account_Name__c is what I need from Company Affiliation, so I dont have to go to Account__c for further info, but will keep ur suggestion in mind.

You are the best!

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider upvoting and/or accepting so it drops off the queue of unanswered questions :)

Comment: Yes, I voted and accepted the answer, thanks again eyescream!